# Compute the dim$Z(v)$ in case $v \neq 0$, $Z(v) = \{ T \in L(V, W) | T(v) = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the dimZ(v).

V and W are finite dimensional vector spaces over $F$. and v is a vector of V and T is a linear Transformation.
Since $v \neq 0$ I know $N(T) \neq 0$,  $T(v) = 0$ $\forall T(v) \in Z(v).$ This implies $1\leq dim N(T) \leq dimV$. I don't know where to go from here. I think you can't get anywhere without knowing what v is or F is.

N(T) is the  nullity of T

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to mathjax/Latex and this site so im having a little difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the map

$$\phi:L(V,W)\to W\,,\,\,\text{defined by}\;\;\phi T:=Tv$$

is linear (proof?), and precisely $\;\ker\phi=Z(v)\;$ . On the other hand, $\;\phi\;$ is *"clearly"* surjective (proof? This is not trivial and perhaps is the hardest part of all this). Now use the dimensions theorem to deduce $\;\dim Z(v)\;$ ...

Comment: $L(V, W)$ are all transformations from V to W. How can you map a transformation to a vector space?

Comment: $\;L(V,W)\;$ is a vector space, and I defined above a map between vector spaces which is linear...Is anything unclear?

Comment: By Tv you mean T(v)?

Comment: @Conor I mean "the map $T$ applied on the vector $v$" . Yes, I guess another way to write that is as $\;T(v)\;$ ...It is the same, of course.

Comment: By the way, I think $$\dim Z(V)=\left(\dim V-1\right)\dim W$$ according to the answer above.